# Run code if no results were found in a MongoDB query in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

I've got this Scala code:

```
Bot.dbUserCollection.find(/*filter*/).first().subscribe(new Observer[Document] {
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = Utils.handleError(msg, e)

  override def onComplete(): Unit = {}

  override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = 
      /*here im doing operations with the result, if found*/
})
```

What is the best way to execute some code only if no result was found? Can I somehow easily check if anything was found in onComplete() maybe? I know this has been asked and anwsered many times for other languages in many places all over the Internet but unfortunately I've found no Scala answer

Comment: Show what you are doing inside `onNext`

Comment: @pedromss, I send a message on a web communicator to the user saying what the result was, and I'd like to tell him that nothing was found, if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that `onNext` will be called when a new document is retrieved and `onComplete` will be called when the operation is complete regardless of whether or not the query returned any results, you can count the number of results in `onNext` and check that count in `onComplete`.

An MVCE follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.{
  MongoClient,
  MongoCollection,
  MongoDatabase,
  Observable,
  Observer
}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object SimpleInsertionAndRetrieval extends App {


  import Helpers._

  // To directly connect to the default server localhost on port 27017
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")
  val doc: Document =
    Document("_id" -> 0, "name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database")

  collection.insertOne(doc).results()

  private def observer = new Observer[Document] {

    private val counter = new AtomicLong(0)

    override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
      println(s"Error: $e")
    }

    override def onComplete(): Unit = {
      val numberOfElements = counter.get()
      if (numberOfElements == 0) {
        println("Nothing was found!")
      } else {
        println(s"There were $numberOfElements")
      }
    }

    override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = {
      counter.incrementAndGet()
      // do other things
    }
  }
  collection
    .find()
    .subscribe(observer)
  collection
    .find(Document("{ _id: 1 }")) // There is no document with _id = 0
    .subscribe(observer)

  Thread.sleep(5000)

  /**
    * From the documentation
    *
    * @see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/tour/Helpers.scala
    */
  object Helpers {

    implicit class DocumentObservable[C](val observable: Observable[Document])
      extends ImplicitObservable[Document] {
      override val converter: (Document) => String = (doc) => doc.toJson
    }

    implicit class GenericObservable[C](val observable: Observable[C])
      extends ImplicitObservable[C] {
      override val converter: (C) => String = (doc) => doc.toString
    }

    trait ImplicitObservable[C] {
      val observable: Observable[C]
      val converter: (C) => String

      def results(): Seq[C] =
        Await.result(observable.toFuture(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

      def headResult() =
        Await.result(observable.head(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

      def printResults(initial: String = ""): Unit = {
        if (initial.length > 0) print(initial)
        results().foreach(res => println(converter(res)))
      }

      def printHeadResult(initial: String = ""): Unit =
        println(s"${initial}${converter(headResult())}")
    }

  }
}
```

This prints

```
There were 1
Nothing was found!
```